# Copy-paste to title from Linux

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Forced to use Linux more often now (thanks to llvm), I noticed that usual way of pasting there doesn't play well with gray text areas, such as 'Title' input box. Pasting by clicking middle button does not trigger deletion of gray text and what's pasted becomes part of it. Title is also considered empty, even if you delete all the gray text yourself.

Comment: The same is true if you use the mouse on Windows (the usual "right-click -> Paste" way). The deletion is triggered by key events only.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved and will be in the next deployment - thanks for the feedback.

In addition to the keydown event, we are now binding

```
bind("contextmenu", clearOverlay)
```